# How to use a variable in firebase.setValue (nativescript-firebase plugin)?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nativescript

I want to store unique user ids provided by Firebase, in my database.

Here is my code:

```
var uid = result.uid;
console.log(uid);
// Prints the unique user id


// Create User structure in FB
firebase.setValue(
  'Users',
  {uid: true}
);
```

This creates the following in FB:

```
Users
  uid: true
```

`uid` is simply that, just a string that says `uid`. Am I doing something incorrect?

([docs](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase/blob/master/docs/DATABASE.md) for reference)

Comment: Have you tried just firebase.setValue( 'Users', uid )?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use `[]` accessor to use the value of the `uid` as a key/property name:

```
var obj = {};
obj[uid] = true;
firebase.setValue('Users', obj);
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets